# How conform to UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerViewDataSource outside of a ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, uipickerviewdatasource, uipickerviewdelegate

I want to have multiple UIPickerViews in one scene without bloating my view controller with delegate functions. All the tutorials I've seen on UIPickerViews suggest using the view controller itself as the delegate of a `UIPickerView`.

How can I move this delegate code out of the `ViewController`?

Inspired by [this tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/22731/ios-uipickerview), here is a view controller that assigns itself as the delegate to it's UIPickerViews. I am critical of the if/else logic used to map behavior to each `UIPickerView`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerViewA: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerViewB: UIPickerView!

    let contentsA = ["1A", "2A", "3A"]
    let contentsB = ["1B", "2B", "3B", "4B"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerViewA.delegate   = self
        pickerViewA.dataSource = self
        pickerViewB.delegate   = self
        pickerViewB.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1 //Applies to both pickerViewA & pickerViewB
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView == pickerViewA {
            return contentsA.count
        } else {
            return contentsB.count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView == pickerViewA {
            return contentsA[row]
        } else {
            return contentsB[row]
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if pickerView == pickerViewA {
            // Do something A
        } else {
            // Do something B
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally I'd like to have a custom class that conforms to these protocols, and then create a new instance of this class for each `UIPickerView` so that they have unique delegates & behaviors.

When I attempt to define a separate class called 'PickerDelegate' that conforms to `UIPickerViewDelegate` & `UIPickerViewDataSource`, I get this error in Xcode:

> Type 'PickerDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'

Apparently `UIPickerViewDelegate` & `UIPickerViewDataSource` inherit from `NSObjectProtocol`. If I add the protocol stubs (as suggested by Xcode), I get a long list of functions I am not keen on implementing.

Is there an easier way to conform to these protocols outside of a view controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I attempt to define a separate class called 'PickerDelegate' that conforms to UIPickerViewDelegate & UIPickerViewDataSource, I get this error in Xcode:

Simply make your PickerDelegate a subclass of NSObject.

```
class PickerDelegate : NSObject, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
```

This is no imposition, and is necessary, because Cocoa is Objective-C and won't even be able to see your delegate and data source methods otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can add extension to like this, and in any UIviewController you want to use UIpiker just setup the delegates in view didload()

```
extension UIViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView == pickerViewA {
            return contentsA.count
        } else {
            return contentsB.count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView == pickerViewA {
            return contentsA[row]
        } else {
            return contentsB[row]
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if pickerView == pickerViewA {
            // Do something A
        } else {
            // Do something B
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a step in the wrong direction because A) View controllers are still being used as delegates and B) Now these delegate methods must handle every UIPickerView everywhere! Spaghetti!